# perl regex keep from match to end of line

Tags: regex, pcre

if i have some error text:

```
"09 30 14:00:21 server01 /opt/www/folder1/cgi-bin/job1.pl[14357]: ALERT: Fatal error connecting to database: DBI connect('database=x1_dataHere;host=server02.gss.bbb.com;port=3308','X1_APP_INFO',...) failed: Access denied for user 'X1_APP_INFO '@' server02.gss.bbb.com' (using password: YES) at /opt/includes/Connector.pm line 13 #01011 main::croak called at /opt/www/folder1/cgi-bin/job1.pl line 15",
```

i want to keep *only* what is after `"ALERT: "`.

how to do that with Perl regex? [?!]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in perl regex:

```
ALERT: \K(.*)$
```

OR

```
(?<=ALERT: )(.*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xY6mC3/2)

Comment: um that is kind of like friggin awesome! may i suffer you to include "ALERT: "? working on it, but chomping at the bit being so close (!)

Comment: i am getting it, removed \K. man that tool is awesome thx very much : ).

Comment: Yes regex101.com is pretty useful for regex testing. `\K` resets starting point of the match.

Comment: final product:
    perl -e 'my $string = "print only the desired ALERT: this msg"; print $string =~ /(ALERT.*)$/;print "\n";'

many thx! tell me if there is a way[more than already] i can give you points. i only know how to say "you answered".

Comment: I think command should be: `perl -e 'my $string = "print only the desired ALERT: this msg"; print $string =~ /ALERT: (.*)$/;print "\n";'` since you're printing message after `"ALERT: "`

Comment: @dcparham - Unless the regex contains a capture group, the print function will just get true/false from the `=~` operator (function). With a capture group, it will display a list result.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting too excited about `\K` you should know that it
stands for 'K'eep everything it matched before \K.
So its the keep behind construct, *not the keep ahead* construct.

All it does is exclude everything up until \K from the *match*
variable `$&` and its primary use is to replace everything  *after*
it (not before), in a substitution `s/before\Kafter//g` effectively
deleting `after`.

Another use for `\K` can be as a variable width look behind assertion.
Example  `/before\s+\Kafter/` where `$&` will contain `after`.

This is frivolous because in Perl, nobody uses the match variable `$&`
(capture group 0) directly because of latency.

If you want to keep past `ALERT:`, just substitute with
`s/^.*?ALERT: //`